# jQuery Tools: only one AJAX tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-tabs

I would like to use [jQuery Tools Tabs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html), and have a set of regular inline content tabs, and one AJAX tab. But I only see samples of either inline content, OR ajax content. Can I mix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it is either all AJAX or none. However, you can easily AJAX a single pane yourself. All you need to do is add a click handler (preferably using [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) so that it removes itself after it is run for the first time) to the tab; this click handler can then load the pane's content with [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) or whatever other AJAX means you want.

For example, the HTML would be something like this:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li id="ajax-tab"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="panes">
    <div>First tab content. Tab contents are called "panes"</div>
    <div>Second tab content</div>
    <div id="ajax-pane"></div>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript would be something like this:

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
$('#ajax-tab').one('click', function() {
    $('#ajax-pane').load('/some/path/that/returns/our/html');
});
```

And here's a simple live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/stxha/